# Scan Barcode/QRcode Flutter web on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter-web

I'm developing a flutter web to scan barcode & qrcode. when accessing from desktop browser, it's run fine (show popup to ask permission using camera), but when accessing from mobile browser (android 10), it keeps show loading widget all time. how can I use camera on mobile browser ?

Note

- I'm using camcode libary (https://pub.dev/packages/camcode)
- for the code, I'm still run the camcode lib example (my code still on early stage)
- testing environment: google chrome mobile browser, already turn on camera permission, run the project from terminal

Comment: Please check for the android 10 updates. Also test it on prior to android 10 versions.

Comment: thanks for the response @msusare . I'll try it

Comment: check this https://pub.dev/packages/qr_bar_code_scanner_dialog/example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trial & error, I found the solution using firebase hosting. so, I build the project then host it on firebase. when accessed, the permission dialog show up